# Converting negative number in the string format to double

Tags: flutter, double, textfield, textformfield

When i use double.parse on my textfield input i get the following error FormatException (FormatException: Invalid double -). [Saw a similar post but problem doesn't seem to be solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74713616/how-to-make-sure-textformfield-input-is-a-numberpositive-or-negative-or-double)

Also how can i prevent user from entering two "." and "-" . Any help is much appreciated. Ty for your time

```
 TextFormField(
          inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^-?\d*.?\d*')),],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true,decimal: true),

          onChanged:(value) {
            setState(() {
              data = double.parse(value);
            });
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'data'
          ),

        ),
```

I tried using RegExp('[0-9.-]') but it doesn't work as well. I still get back the same error message as stated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double.parse is expecting a double as string. So when you enter a dot (.) or a dash (-) and it tries to parse it as a double, it throws an exception. You need to apply some checks in order to solve this.

Try this

```
TextFormField(
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^-?\d*.?\d*')),
      ],
      keyboardType:
          TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true),
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty && value != '.' && value != '-') {
          setState(() {
            data = double.parse(value);
          });
        }
      },
      decoration:
          InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'data'),
    ),
```

Comment: hmm its still not working when i key in negative values. The moment i click on -  at the start the following error occur : 
Exception has occured 
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid double
)

Comment: I understand your problem now. Basically what's happening here is that when you enter a dot (.) or a dash (-) as the first character, double.parse cannot parse it as a double since neither are of double type so it throws an exception. To solve this you will need to apply some checks like

if (value.isNotEmpty && value != '.' && value != '-') {
                data = double.parse(value);
              }

I'll also edit to answer to this